# Comparing 2 strings c#

Tags: c#, string, compare

So I have a string which I split in half. Now I need to compare both parts of the string and output has to be all the elements that are the same in both of them.

I noticed some people using Intersect, but I don't know why it doesn't work for me, I get really weird output if I use it.

So here is my code:

```
string first= "1 3 6 8 4 11 34 23 3 1 7 22 24 8"
int firstLength = first.Length;
        int half = firstLength / 2;
        string S1 = first.Substring(0, half);
        string  S2= first.Substring(half, half);

        var areInCommon = S1.Intersect(S2);

        Console.WriteLine("Numbers that these 2 strings have in common are: ");
        foreach (int i in areInCommon)
            Console.WriteLine(i);
```

So in this case output would be: 1, 3 and 8.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do a split on space after the substring lines

Comment: A string is just a sequence of characters. Even though this particular string appears to you to be a sequence of numbers (some of which have two digits), the string itself doesn't care about that. It only cares about the individual characters: `'1'`, `' '`, `'3'`, `' '`, `'6'`, `' '`, `'8'`, `' '`, `'4'`, `' '`, `'1'`, `'1'`, and so on. The `Intersect` method will therefore operate on individual characters rather than numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close what you really want is arrays of the numbers not arrays of chars... you can get that with the split function.

```
string first= "1 3 6 8 4 11 34 23 3 1 7 22 24 8"
int firstLength = first.Length;
int half = firstLength / 2;
string S1 = first.Substring(0, half);
string  S2= first.Substring(half, half);

var areInCommon = S1.Split(" ".ToArray()).Intersect(S2.Split(" ".ToArray());

Console.WriteLine("Numbers that these 2 strings have in common are: ");
foreach (var i in areInCommon)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

---

A note about using ToArray():

I use ToArray() out of habit and the reason is that if you want to pass in parameters you can't do it without this construct.  For example if the data looked like this:

```
 string first= "1, 3, 6, 8, 4, 11, 34, 23, 3, 1, 7, 22, 24, 8"
```

then we would need to use

```
 .Split(" ,".ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

since this happens a lot, I use the `.ToArray()` out of habit.  You can also use a new construct (eg `new char [] { ' ', ',' }` ) I find that more cumbersome, but probably slightly faster.

Comment: Why not just `Split(' ')` instead of `Split(" ".ToArray())`?

Comment: Yes it does `public string[] Split (params char[] separator)` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The [`params`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) lets you do something like `mystring.Split(' ', '-', '/');`  or just `mystring.Split(' ');`

Comment: if you want to pass char parameter in Split method use single quotation. Why go for " ".ToArray() ?

Answer (score 0):

simply split both the string within an array and them compare both the strings using `contains()` function.

Answer (score 0):

`string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`, thus, you're intersecting sequences of characters instead of strings.

You should use `String.Split`:

```
IEnumerable<string> S1 = first.Substring(0, half).Split(' ');
IEnumerable<string> S2= first.Substring(half, half).Split(' ');
```

And then your intersection will output the desired result.

Also, you can convert each string representation of numbers into integers (i.e. `int`):

```
IEnumerable<int> S1 = first.Substring(0, half).Split(' ').Select(s => int.Parse(s));
IEnumerable<int> S2 = first.Substring(half, half).Split(' ').Select(s => int.Parse(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting all your characters into integers. The character '1' is not represented by the integer 1. Change your foreach to:

```
foreach (char i in areInCommon)
```